# Можно ли как-то реализовать дебаг для систем написанных на PHP?

Tags: отладка, php, smarty

Всем доброго времени суток!

Ситуация такая. Есть MVC -система ,написанная на PHP+Smarty.
Но как такого дебага у нас нет - постоянно делаем или **echo** ,или в Smarty **var_dump** , или **console.log** .
Все это крайне неудобно и примитивно ,и далеко от того дебаггера, к которому все привыкли.

Вот собственно и назрел такой ворпос - можно ли как-то реализовать дебаг для систем написанных на PHP?

Comment: А чем вас xdebug не устроил ?

Answer (score 3):

Xdebug вам в помощь. Он не очень охотно встает на денвер, но в целом, после установки, решит все ваши описанные проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо! Будем "курить"...

Comment: и еще. Он debUg. От приставки de и английского bug - жук(в общем случае все мелкие членистоногие), оно же обозначает ошибку в программе.

debAgger - это исключатель сумок. =/